# How do I set the position of a vertical scrollbar in VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net, textbox, scrollbar

I have a TextBox control with a lot of text which has a vertical scrollbar, and every time I hide/show the control the position of the scrollbar stays the same. I'm trying to figure out how to change the position of the scrollbar to the top of the textbox, as if it were at the beginning of the text.

How would I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are using WinForms, this is a possible solution:

```
YourTextBox.Select(0, 0)
YourTextBox.ScrollToCaret()
```

If you are using WPF:

```
YourTextBox.ScrollToHome()
```

Comment: I'm using forms, and that doesn't seem to do anything.

Comment: Never mind, I accidentally put the code in the wrong place. Thank you.